# How to optimize this select with join and order-by?

Tags: mysql, optimization, select, order-by, aurora

We have two tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
....
  `subject_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `text_id` (`text_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `subject_id` (`subject_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=237542180 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

The second one:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` char(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `password` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
...................
  `moderation` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tag` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `created` (`reg_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=123585 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

messages has ~49M records, users has 13k. DB engine: Aurora(MySQL-Compatible) 5.6.10a

The terribly long request is

```
SELECT messages.*, users.administrator_group_id FROM messages 
    LEFT JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id 
    ORDER BY messages.id desc LIMIT 0,20
```

If I run this request without `order by` then it takes 14-16 sec. With `order` it takes longer than 5 min.

I considering change business logic to avoid this request and limit recordset from `messages` e.g. by messages date but would like to know if there is any way to speed it up on the same hardware as is.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ why not make the query in your comment your answer ??? I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ works like a charm, Thank you! Please turn your comment into answer.

Comment: Thnx @RolandoMySQLDBA, I did as advised ;) I wasn't sure as I have never used Aurora. How diverged is it from mainstream MySQL (if you know)?

Comment: AFAIK Aurora is a some kind of framework written into the Storage Engine for MySQL and PostgreSQL, making it Multi-AZ aware. It should not have any real bearing on SELECT performance as far as I can tell (unless a replica is not reachable and SELECTs reroute to the Primary, thus a hiccup)

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key, so drop the `UNIQUE(id)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used Aurora and there might differences with MySQL but there is a method that works very often in MySQL in similar issues, when the execution plan is not optimal, i.e. when it does the joins first and then has to do the `ORDER BY` of the big intermediate result set.

Instead of joining the 2 tables, we try to first `LIMIT` the results in a derived table and then `JOIN` back. This way indexes will be used for the `ORDER BY - LIMIT` and then it will only have to do N seeks (20 in this case) in the 2nd table:

```
SELECT 
    m.*, 
    u.administrator_group_id 
FROM 
    ( SELECT id 
      FROM messages 
      ORDER BY id DESC 
      LIMIT 20
    ) AS mi
  JOIN 
    messages AS m ON m.id = mi.id
  LEFT JOIN 
    users AS u ON m.user_id = u.id 
ORDER BY 
    mi.id DESC ;
```

And a variation:

```
SELECT 
    m.*, 
    u.administrator_group_id 
FROM 
    ( SELECT mi.* 
      FROM messages AS mi 
      ORDER BY mi.id DESC 
      LIMIT 20
    ) AS m
  LEFT JOIN 
    users AS u ON m.user_id = u.id 
ORDER BY 
    m.id DESC ;
```

Try both and check execution plan and performance. In any reasonable hardware a query that just gets 20 rows from a table or two and uses indexes should be really efficient. In milliseconds range, not seconds or minutes.